# Why promiscuous mode gets set automatically — and should I be worried?

Tags: linux, networking

Our general webhosting server (LAMP with Parallels Plesk) started to turn `PROMISCUOUS` mode `ON` on `eth0` "by itself".

I noticed the change in configuration on 2013-11-08 when `rkhunter` warned us from "Possible promiscuous interfaces" which hadn't happened before. After a bit of googling I didn't find any real use case for promiscuous mode on our server, so I disabled it using `# ifconfig eth0 -promisc` only to find out a day later the flag has been re-set.

Here's what kernel logs says:

```
Nov  8 14:51:31 hallinta kernel: [3301285.098047] klogd1 uses obsolete (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)
Nov  8 14:51:31 hallinta kernel: [3301285.099528] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 11 08:34:18 hallinta kernel: [3537242.374911] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
Nov 12 07:46:30 hallinta kernel: [3620559.485388] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 13 08:47:36 hallinta kernel: [3710393.877512] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
Nov 14 07:53:49 hallinta kernel: [3793353.202243] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 14 09:16:03 hallinta kernel: [3798274.154435] device eth0 left promiscuous mode
```

I included the `klogd1` message because of its immediate timestamp. From auth logs I didn't see any suspicious activity around the first "entered promiscuous mode" message.

As the two enterings' timestamps are roughly similar I checked if I had any cronjobs running around that time. Most of the daily jobs (I searched with [this tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137173)) are run at 06:25 the latest and next job is run at 08:00. None of those 06:25 jobs contained the words `ifconfig` or `promisc`.

**What could set promiscuous mode ON** on `eth0` interfaces and should I be worried? (I am, but should I be?) Is there any legit reason promiscuous mode should be set on?

Comment: Does the host run any VMs?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The host is a virtual server but does not host any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `vnstat` is the process putting the interface in promiscuous mode, check its logfiles and see if thit is logged (depends on logging verbosity of course). If there is no reason to monitor traffic, just disable it and see how it goes.

I suspect that promiscuous mode must be on while `rkhunter` is running, in order for `rkhunter` to detect it.

What is very very weird, is this:

```
Nov  8 14:51:31 hallinta kernel: [3301285.098047] klogd1 uses obsolete (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)
Nov  8 14:51:31 hallinta kernel: [3301285.099528] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
```

AFAIK there is no such thing as `klogd1` (there is a `klogd` of course), and there shouldn't be one. Take the time to check if there is a binary under that name and if there is a `klogd1` process (if yes, find what it is doing). If `vnstat` is not doing that, then there is a high chance that your machine might have been compromised.

Comment: Just from a quick Google search `klogd1` doesn't look legitimate. There's at least 3 rootkit questions on the first page: https://www.google.com/search?q=klogd1

Answer (score 6):

Someone is probably running a packet sniffer, tcpdump, wireshark, etc.  Look at last to see who was logging in.  Double check the sudoers log if you have that configured.

Comment: Sniffing was the most probable resaon to enable `promisc` in such an environment, based on what I read too. How can I confirm someone/something is sniffing? I checked the auth log from November and all ssh logins were from our offices' IPs (except for two sftp connections which were from one of our clients' IP and using, of course, more restricted chrooted account).

Comment: Are you running some traffic monitoring application e.g. ntop ?

Comment: @jijix It seems we do have `vnstat` service running—although I see no difference in stats around times when I had turned promisc off (should I?). And, if the promiscuous mode was enabled all the time (I have no clue, I'm doing this more or less IATOD), I wonder why `rkhunter` started to warn about it not until last Friday.

Comment: Not necessarily - I'm also getting "device ethF entered promiscuous mode" message in logs and only myself has access to a standard Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instance that's only used to run a couple of shell scripts. It was an out of the box installation and no additional packages installed nor mods made to config. I still don't know why it's doing it in particular after reboot thus triggering AlertLogic attack alert notifications.